# Pass javascript variable to angularjs scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flask

I am using flask to render an html template.  I would like to pass variable add_html_data, that I pass through flask's render_template, to an AngularJs controllers scope.

I tried

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="layoutController" ng-init="entries= {{ add_html_metadata|tojson }}"/>
</body>
```

In this case {{}} represent flask variables (I changed angularjs binding syntax to {[{}]}).

Also, I tried creating an intermediary javascript variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">var entries = {{ add_html_metadata|tojson }}</script>
```

But, still cannot figure out how to attach it to the controllers scope.

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: You now have a global variable `entries`. Since global variables are available anywhere in js code.... inside an angular controller or directive or service `$scope.entries=entries`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `init()` function in your controller:

```
app.controller('layoutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function(html_metadata) {
        $scope.html_metadata = html_metadata;
    }
});
```

Then in your template you can invoke this function with the data:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="layoutController" ng-init="init({{ add_html_metadata|tojson }})"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Miguel's answer may work, but I would just create a restful call to return the JSON blob of data defined as `add_html_metadata`, and use a `$http` request to put that on the controller's scope, thats the angular way to do things. Something like this:

```
@app.route("/html_metadata", methods=["GET"])
def get_html_metadata():
   #do something in here
   return jsonify(html_metadata)
```

And in the angular controller

```
myApp.controller('layoutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/html_metadata'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.html_metadata = data
   }); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with flask, anyways, Try to use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)